# Stacked jQuery UI accordions not resizing

Tags: javascript, css, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery-ui, accordion

Be gentle I am new to this web dev game. I'm just trying to learn.

CODE:

```
<h4>Monday</h4>
<div id="first_accordian"> 
    <h5>First Section</h5>
    <div>
        Some stuff. 
    </div>
    <h5>Second Section</h5>
    <div>
        Some stuff. 
    </div>
</div>

<h4>Tuesday</h4>
<div id="second_accordian"> 
    <h5>First Section</h5>
    <div>
        Some stuff. 
    </div> 
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $("[id$=_accordian]").accordion({ collapsible: true, active: false });
    });
</script>
```

Obviously this is just a simplification of a partial view I have in and ASP.NET MVC3 app. But I am using jQuery UI and the accordion widget, so you will need to reference those for the code above to work.

QUESTION:

I have an issue here that when I expand an accordion element it will overlay any HTML underneath it. The behaviour I want is that I have a set of stacked accordions that all shift up or down when any element is selected in any of the accordions.

Does anyone know how I can do this with stacked accordions? Or thinking laterally. Is there any way I can add static headers that aren't accordion elements inline to the accordion (show above as the headers above each accordion; Monday, Tuesday)?

Is there are resizing event of something I should bind to? I'm at a loss as to where to start, any pointers welcome!

EDIT: Have just copied my own code into a file to check and experiment... and it works exactly how I need it to. But it doesn't in my app. So I'm guessing this must be down to something else going on outside of my code.

So... New question: What could stop something from resizing and creating this overlay problem?

Comment: How have you positioned your stacked elements? If they're positioned then it's likely that you'll get the behaviour you're seeing. Try floating the elements instead and they _should_ move when the accordion expands

Comment: I have positioned them just as I have in the code. They are in a containing <div/>... what do you meant 'floating' the elements?

Comment: try setting overflow: hidden; to the parent container (if there is one) and then set float: left; on each of the h4/first_accordion/second_accordion elements

Comment: Doesn't seem to work. The "overflow: hidden" shifts the whole lot to the right of the page and the "float: left" does just that, the headings float to the side, but the expanding accordion still overlays the ones below... like a classic combo box type action. I want them all to slide down out of the way...

Comment: Is there any way you could knock up a jsfiddle of what you have? It'd be a bit easier if I could play with the working code

Comment: I have done just that... bit annoying trying to get all the code into the jsfiddle, lots of copy paste of the partial views from all the Ajax stuff... however. It works perfectly in the environment there as well... I'm going to see if I can find the missing link!